# XmlHttpRequest and AEM Servlet

Tags: xmlhttprequest, aem

I am making an raw ajax call on the clientside, which look like the following,

```
var url = '/bin/denisa/dummyServlet';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01');
xhr.onload = function() {
 if (xhr.status === 200) {
alert('deni');

 }
   else {
   alert('Request failed. Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

to the following servlet in AEM:

```
@Component(
   service = {
   Servlet.class
   },
   property = {
   "sling.servlet.paths=/bin/denisa/dummyServlet",
   "sling.servlet.extensions=json",
   "sling.servlet.methods=GET"
   }
)
public class DummyServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

   private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyServlet .class);

   @Reference
   private dummyService dummyService;

   @Override
   protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(dummyService);
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(jsonElement));
  }
}
```

And I got a 404, and i don't know exactly why because the path is the same, and also contentTypes. Does anybody has a clue?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good it seems something is missing on the config side

can you log in to the felix console 
http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles

Expand you project bundle and check for your servlet
with Service ID xx  Types: javax.servlet.Servlet and other details 
*Also ensure the bundle is not installed and in active state

Then go to http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr and verify  Apache Sling Servlet/Script Resolver execution paths contain /bin/ entry

If above mentioned configs are navigate to  http://localhost:4502/system/console/servletresolver
check for servlet response.

These are some of the configuration which helped me to resolve 404